# Need help in finding extrema in a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I would greatly appreciate, if someone helped me spot an error in my logic:

I have a function $f(x) = \sqrt{3}\cos{x} + \sin{x}$ and I need to find its extrema on the closed interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

First, I'd like to point where the error is supposed to be. At the bottom I'll put the details. I found points, where the derivative of the function has 0 values and together with the end points the behavior of the function looks like this:

```
     f'(0.1)≈0.82   f'(1)≈-0.9   f'(Pi)=-1 f'(4)≈0.65
          +             -              -
----+--------------+-------------+----------------+---->
    0            ≈0.47         ≈2.67             2Pi
```

As you can see the derivative changes its sign somewhere between Pi and 4 (at least), but there is no root between 2.67 and 2Pi.

***This is how I attempted to solve it:***

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{3}\cos{x} + \sin{x} \\
f'(x) = -\sqrt{3}\sin{x} + \cos{x} \\
-\sqrt{3}\sin{x} + \cos{x} = 0 \\
-\sin^2{x} -\sqrt{3}\sin{x} + 1 = 0 \\
D = 3 + 4 = 7  \\
\sin{x} = \frac{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}}{-2} \approx -2.18 \to \emptyset \\
\sin{x} = \frac{\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{7}}{-2} \approx 0.45 \\
x = \arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{7}}{-2}) \approx 0.47 \\
x = \pi - \arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{7}}{-2}) \approx 2.67
$$

So somehow I must have missed at least one root. Can somebody suggest something here? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to put $a \cos x +b \sin x$ into the form $r \cos (x+\alpha)$? If not, try to work out what $r$ and $\alpha$ should be using basic trig identities (expand the second form and equate coefficients, remembering that $r$ and $\alpha$ are constants). If you work out how to use this method you will find this kind of question rather easy to tackle.

Comment: Are you changing $cos(x)$ to $1-sin(x)^2$?

Comment: @87091403130 yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error:

$-\sqrt{3}\sin{x} + \cos{x} = 0 \nRightarrow$

$-\sin^2{x} -\sqrt{3}\sin{x} + 1 = 0, \;since$

$\cos{x}\neq -\sin^2{x}+ 1,\;but\; \cos^2{x}= -\sin^2{x}+ 1$

Then

$-\sqrt{3}\sin{x} + \cos{x} = 0,\; 
\cos{x}\neq  0$

$ tanx=\frac {1}{\sqrt3}$

$ x=\frac{\pi}{6}+ \pi k,\;\; k\in \ Z$

Answer (score 2):

To find your critical points, note that $$-\sqrt{3}\sin(x)+\cos(x)=0\implies \cos(x)=\sqrt{3}\sin(x)\implies\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\tan(x)$$ $$\implies\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}=\tan(x)\text{ or } \frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}=\tan(x)$$  On the finite interval $[0,2\pi]$, we have that $$\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}=\tan(x)\ \implies x=\frac{\pi}{6}$$ and $$\frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}=\tan(x)\implies x=\frac{7\pi}{6}$$

Therefore we have $4$ points to test for extrema, namely the endpoints and the critical points. Observe: $$f(0)=\sqrt{3}\cos(0)+\sin(0)=\sqrt{3}$$ $$f\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\sqrt{3}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=2$$ $$f\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)=\sqrt{3}\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)=-2$$ $$f(2\pi)=\sqrt{3}\cos(2\pi)+\sin(2\pi)=\sqrt{3}$$

So on $[0,2\pi]$, $f(x)$ has a maximum of $2$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and a minimum of $-2$ at $x=\frac{7\pi}{6}$.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x) = \sqrt{3}\cos x + \sin x = 2\cos\big( \frac{\pi}{6}-x \big)$ and now, $f'(x) = 2\sin\big( \frac{\pi}{6}-x \big)$, which is zero if and only if 
$$\frac{\pi}{6}-x = k\pi \qquad k = 0,1,2,\dots$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: What formula did you use for $\sqrt{3}\cos{x} + \sin{x} = 2\cos{(\pi/6 - x)}$ ?

Comment: It is just the sine of the two angles sum.